# SpringBoot App Stopped Working - Security Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I've built an SpringBoot APP using a tutorial from YouTube. It worked flawlessly, did everything i could (wrote all the code from the video, fixed parts where the code wasn't working \ component was deprecated, etc). So far so good.

However, after i moved the project to another folder it just stopped working. The log shows something like:

> Using generated security password:
> 762a8270-b075-45b5-ba17-691aa31d86cb
>
> This generated password is for development use only. Your security
> configuration must be updated before running your application in
> production.

From what i've read, its something about the security in the app.
I'm using JWT and correctly configured securityFilterChain (since WebSecurityConfigureAdapter is deprecated). The app was working fine, it just stopped working after i moved it from another folder (moved using InteliJ).

I've also tried to clone my latest commit from github to another folder, but the problem persisted. Nothing changed.

Here's the full initialization log:

```
2023-03-10T11:52:27.803-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] c.i.c.CafeManagementSystemApplication    : Starting CafeManagementSystemApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 19088 (C:\Portfolio\Cafe Management System (Angular, Spring Boot - Java, MySQL Database)\Java\com.inn.cafe\target\classes started by Pablo in C:\Portfolio\Cafe Management System (Angular, Spring Boot - Java, MySQL Database)\Java)
2023-03-10T11:52:27.808-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] c.i.c.CafeManagementSystemApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-10T11:52:28.784-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-10T11:52:28.816-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-10T11:52:29.696-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-03-10T11:52:29.710-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-10T11:52:29.711-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-10T11:52:29.827-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-10T11:52:29.829-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1940 ms
2023-03-10T11:52:30.097-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-10T11:52:30.183-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-03-10T11:52:30.535-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-10T11:52:30.882-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2cae5fa7
2023-03-10T11:52:30.885-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-10T11:52:30.952-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-03-10T11:52:31.502-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-10T11:52:31.513-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-10T11:52:32.119-03:00  WARN 19088 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 762a8270-b075-45b5-ba17-691aa31d86cb

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2023-03-10T11:52:32.296-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3b8d2abe, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6669cba, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4ab90d01, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@35af1558, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1edac3b4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e2a76be, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@b842275, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3a116ca6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@37c74e4e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4a6ef712, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2d88c1bf, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@56d5460f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@128a188a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@72b10258, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@44c27b8b]
2023-03-10T11:52:32.397-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-10T11:52:32.410-03:00  INFO 19088 --- [           main] c.i.c.CafeManagementSystemApplication    : Started CafeManagementSystemApplication in 5.17 seconds (process running for 5.761)
```

I've read several pages around SO, and most of em just tell to do this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

To exclude SecurityAutoConfiguration.class on springboot main initializer. However i need to authenticate users on my app, i can't disable security.

Is there anything i'm missing? I'll show here my SecurityConfig class, i believe its the only one that may have something to do with this issue. Any additional information required just post on the comments and i'll edit the question.

Thanks in advance for any input!

package com.inn.cafe.JWT;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig    {
    @Autowired
    CustomerUserDetailsService customerUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer(){
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/users/login", "/users/signup","/users/forgotPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        var encodedPwd = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encodedPwd;
    }
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customerUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/user/login")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/signup")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/forgotPassword")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();



      http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

      http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());


        return http.build();
    }



}
```

EDIT: Some information.

1. SpringBoot main class in on the top.
2. Tried to add:

> @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.inn.cafe")

Nothing changed.

3. It isn't scanning my SecurityConfig class. I added a few log entries there, and nothing was shown when i started the app.
4. Using @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity on the SecurityConfig class.
5. I'm not using WebSecurityConfigureAdpter. I'm aware its deprecated.

Comment: `after i moved the project to another folder it just stopped working` show your folder structure for your project. What did you move?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I moved the main class, the one with @SpringBootApplication, to a different folder (bootloader). So since it was not on a higher or same level than my security classes, the security classes started to be ignored.

So I just moved the main class to my root package and security started to work again.